# Hadoop mapreduce python command line arguments

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, command-line-arguments

In my python mapper code, I need to access the 'path' given in -input 'path'. How is it possible to access this in python code?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the input file from `os.environ`. For example,

```
import os
input_file = os.environ['map_input_file']
```

Actually, you can also read other JobConf from `os.environ`. Note: During the execution of a streaming job, the names of the "mapred" parameters are transformed. The dots ( . ) become underscores ( _ ). For example, mapred.job.id becomes mapred_job_id and mapred.jar becomes mapred_jar. To get the values in a streaming job's mapper/reducer use the parameter names with the underscores. See [Configured Parameters](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html#Configured+Parameters).

I also find a very useful post for you: [A Guide to Python Frameworks for Hadoop](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/).